# {System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I am trying to validate my model. It is returning false every time. Below is my controller ,view and model code. Does anyone have Idea about this?

My controller is like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registration(Register reg)
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //some code
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
              //some code
            }
        }
```

My View is like

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "ArcherRegistration" }))
    {
<body>
                    <legend>Details</legend>
                    <div class="top">
                        @Html.Label("Select School: ")                     
                        @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.lstSchool, new SelectList(Model.lstSchool, "Key", "Value"),new { @class = "defaultTextBox", @id = "ddlSchools"})*@                                         
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedSchool, 
                        new SelectList(Model.lstSchool, "Key", "Value"),"--Select--",
                        new { @class = "defaultTextBox", @id = "ddlSchools"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedSchool,"",new {@class="field-validation-error"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="top">
                        @Html.Label("Enter Name: ")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name, "",new { @class = "defaultTextBox",@maxlength = "50"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                    <div class="top">
                        @Html.Label("Select Archer Gender: ")            
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedGender, 
                   new SelectList(Model.Gender, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--",
                        new {@class = "defaultTextBox"})   
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedGender)          
                    </div> 
</body>
    }
```

My model is:

```
 public class Register
    {


        public int tourID {get ; set;}
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "School")]
        public string selectedSchool { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> lstSchool { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Limit exceeds 50")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only characters are allowed")]
        [Display(Name = "Archer Name")]
        public string ArcherName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public string selectedGender { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Grade")]
        public string selectedGrade { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> lstGrade { get; set; }

    }
```

Even If I fill in all the details in model, My model does not validates. It throws System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion error.

Comment: why are you using a `<body>` tag? `<body>`s aren't supposed to be in `<form>`s, that could be causing an issue.

Comment: No, This is not causing the problem. There is something wrong with dropdown binding. I am unable to figure it out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is required for a dropdown list, but that is an interface and not a solid implementation... e.g. "what sort of `IEnumerable` should I create when I serialise? I have no idea!"

Change that member to a `List<SelectListItem>`

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public string selectedGender { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Gender { get; set; }
```

As that list is *read only* data, there is no point sending it back to the sever at all. Just put it in the `ViewBag` instead. Same goes for the other two `Dictionary` based members.

Just make sure you cast the ViewBag properties to the correct type, in the view, or it will assume `object` and fail with another error :)